# ISCSI device and partitions used in ISCSI client

Tags: iscsi, device

The command list all devices including ISCSI.

```
cat /proc/partitions
```

Is it possible to know which device is currently used by a given target?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
root@localhost # ls -l /dev/disk/by-path

lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root  9 Apr 26 10:00 ip-192.168.122.1:3260-iscsi-iscsi240420141:target0-lun-1 -> ../../sdb
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root  9 Apr 26 09:43 ip-192.168.122.1:3260-iscsi-iscsi240420142:target1-lun-1 -> ../../sda
```